# Implement ImageSearchDLL.dll in C#

Tags: c#, image, search, dll

I am trying to use ImageSearchDLL.dll in Visual Studio C#. I used to use it in AutoIt.

Following is the code I came up with to use the [Imagesearch](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/) Function. However, as soon as it tried to call ImageSearch, the program crashes without any exception.
I have the dll file included in my project folder. Could it be because of that although I was able to use the dll in AutoIt, it doesn't mean it would work in C# as well?
Note: I tried both 32 and 64 bits of .dll

```
    [DllImport("ImageSearchDLL.dll")]
    static extern string ImageSearch(int aLeft, int aTop, int aRight, int aBottom, string aImageFile);

    public static int Search(String FilePath, int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2, ref int X, ref int Y, int tolerance, int resultPosition)
    {
        if (tolerance > 0) 
        {
            FilePath = "*" + tolerance.ToString() + " " + FilePath;
        }

        string result = ImageSearch(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, "test.png"); **<- crash here**
        string[] result_array = result.Split('|');
        if (result_array[0] == "0" )
            return 0;
        X = Convert.ToInt32(result_array[2]);
        Y = Convert.ToInt32(result_array[3]);
        if (resultPosition == 1)
        {
            X = X + (Convert.ToInt32(result_array[4]))/2;
            Y = Y + (Convert.ToInt32(result_array[5]))/2;
        }
        return 1;       
    }
```

Comment: Did you put a `try...catch` around the line where it crashes, and see if you can catch the exception?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use try and catch, but it does not show any message neither. But I got this in the output box below: 'AKD Morph.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Osz\Desktop\AKD Morph\AKD Morph 20140304\AKD Morph\bin\Debug\AKD Morph.exe', Symbols loaded.
The program '[8608] AKD Morph.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f).

Comment: If you've single-stepped your code in the debugger and you're *certain* that the crash happens on the call to `ImageSearch`, and it exits without any error message whatsoever, then I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I am certain the crash happens on the call. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To call a function from a dll, you need to know its calling convention and types of parameters as seen by the compiler that created the dll. So far I can see you have your parameters in reverse order, missing two "ref"s and missing the last parameter, hbmp, whatever it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't have to do with using C#. If the method is called with the same parameters (type and value) the DLL has to work the same way.

I used a bit different method signature than yours and it worked for me:

```
[DllImport("ImageSearchDLL.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr ImageSearch(int x, int y, int right, int bottom, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string imagePath);
```

Other than that, you should verify that the DLL is found and can be imported (consider using `SetDLLDirectory`)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public static extern bool SetDllDirectory([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pathName);
```

This is how I used the `ImageSearch` maybe it'll help you:

```
public static String[] UseImageSearch(string imgPath)
{
    int right = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right;
    int bottom = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom;

    IntPtr result = ImageSearch(0, 0, right, bottom, imgPath);
    String res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);

    if (res[0] == '0') return null;//not found

    String[] data = res.Split('|');
    //0->found, 1->x, 2->y, 3->image width, 4->image height;        

    // Then, you can parse it to get x and y:
    int x; int y;
    int.TryParse(data[1], out x);
    int.TryParse(data[2], out y);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to execute it with a saved .png image and I'm getting this exception: System.BadImageFormatException... Any ideas? Maybe I could send a bitmap loaded in memory?

Comment: Maybe your image isn't a `png`? If I were you I'd google this exception and try as many combinations as possible. It would work eventually.

Comment: Hello, my image is a png, and after some google, the error is related to bad dll format, it's not about the image, it's about the dll, I forgot to update my comment here.. I made my own C# ImageSearch anyways which is way faster than this dll but I'm still curious on why this doesn't work