# C# ImageSearch DLL

Tags: c#, image, dll, screen

So I have recently made a program which finds specific image on the screen and returns the location of it, I actually found this part of the code on stackoverflow, which is using ImageSearch.dll from AutoIT3.

It works pretty well, however, there's one thing missing and I have no idea how to do it. I mean tolerance. This is the original definition of what it does:

```
";                $tolerance - 0 for no tolerance (0-255). Needed when colors of
;                            image differ from desktop. e.g GIF"
```

Basically allows to find the image even if there are a few differences.

So this is the code I've got:

```
    DllImport("ImageSearch.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ImageSearch(int x, int y, int right, int bottom, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string imagePath);

        public static string[] UseImageSearch(string imgPath)
    {

        IntPtr result = ImageSearch(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom, imgPath);
        string res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);

        if (res[0] == '0') return null;

        string[] data = res.Split('|');

        int x; int y;
        int.TryParse(data[1], out x);
        int.TryParse(data[2], out y);

        return data;
    }
```

And I'd like to somehow make the tolerance work as it is in the original. Is that possible? Thanks for any help!

Comment: A little googling returned this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184246/implement-imagesearchdll-dll-in-c-sharp
The OP has done an implementation to include tolerance.

Comment: @AtanuRoy Haha! I'm so dumb, I literally was there and that's where I found the code, I just didn't notice that the OP had made the tolerance, damn I"m so blind.

Comment: So, if I add something like this:
       ` if (tolerance > 0) 
        {
            FilePath = "*" + tolerance.ToString() + " " + FilePath;
        }`

this should already work?

Comment: I have not tried it myself. However it looks like the original documentation that you mentioned are actually from AutoIT scripts. Here is the implementation - https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/

Comment: Well yeah, it's almost the first time I implement some foreign DLL and work with it, so I don't really know how to work with it by myself and most of what I've done there is by googling stuff and trying to learn from it. I'm going to check if it's worked.

Comment: @AtanuRoy I don't think it has worked, and idk why it would by adding " *xxx " on the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually wanting to do the same thing so I figured I would post how I did it. I added a second parameter, `string tolerance`, to UseImageSearch() and appended the `tolerance` string, prefixed with an * and postfixed with a space to the imgPath string, I passed the new string to the DLL and it returned a string[] with the desired results.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
```

I referenced these guys

```
[DllImport(@"C:\ImageSearchDLL.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ImageSearch(int x, int y, int right, int bottom, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string imagePath);

    public static string[] UseImageSearch(string imgPath, string tolerance)
    {
        imgPath = "*" + tolerance + " " + imgPath;

        IntPtr result = ImageSearch(0, 0, 1920, 1080, imgPath);
        string res = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);

        if (res[0] == '0') return null;

        string[] data = res.Split('|');

        int x; int y;
        int.TryParse(data[1], out x);
        int.TryParse(data[2], out y);

        return data;
    }
```

Then I called UseImageSearch using the image path and the desired tolerance level 0-255

```
 string image = (@"C:\Capture.PNG");

        string[] results = UseImageSearch(image, "30");
        if (results == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("null value bro, sad day");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(results[1] + ", " + results[2]);
        }
```

It performed as desired.

[image]